# npm ReferenceError: primordials is not defined (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, referenceerror

I know this question is posted many times but I tried the solutions and I can not resolve it. I am trying to work wit npm however I get this error:

```
     evalmachine.<anonymous>:35
    } = primordials;
        ^
    
    ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
        at evalmachine.<anonymous>:35:5
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:8)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
```

I can not even execute `npm -v`  to see the version.
I tried to downgrade node to version 10.
I tried to uninstall-reinstall node so many times (From remove application settings).
I tried to create a file called "npm-shrinkwrap.json" insde the npm folder where package.json exists.
But there is no use.

And I can't see an "AppData" folder in the "Users/User" path but I can access it by "cd" from the command line. I don't understand how it is not visible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is resolved!

I know I said I uninstalled npm, but just uninstalling it from the settings were not enough. I tried to uninstall it deleting the node releted directories on my computer following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/13806114. And then I installed node again and it worked!

Thank you.

Comment: In my case these directories (C:\Users\..\npm and npm-cache) contained a lot of stuff and all files were pretty old 2015-2017 from a previous abandoned nodejs installation. The surprising thing is that after installing nodejs, running successfuly npm install -  the file node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js was not used at all, actually my directory C:\Users\..\npm is empty. That means the behavior of npm is condicionated by an old script structure which I think is very bad idea / design, at least very confusing as this error shows.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for the "primordials" method in graceful-fs, trying to reinstall this dependency.

About npm, try reinstalling nodejs again, probably your npm is corrupted

About AppData is not visible or is a hidden directory in Windows, you can access it by path in Windows Explorer

Comment: I reinstalled and it worked. Thank you. (I couldn't manage to uninstall properly before)