# npm cannot run evalmachine.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I got this problem for a while can't find any solution , please give me some explain.

```
C:\Users\ASUS ZenBook I5>npm -v
evalmachine.<anonymous>:27
const { Math, Object } = primordials;
                         ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:27:26
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS ZenBook I5\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS ZenBook I5\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
```

node.js
v12.13.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [npm ReferenceError: primordials is not defined (node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898016/npm-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-node-js)

The problem seems to be `graceful-fs` - maybe it's even enough to run the following?

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall node go to `\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm` delete this `npm` folder, now install `node nad` that is all.